# Getting NullPointerException on commit - orientdb in baasbox code

Tags: orientdb, baasbox

I am getting a NullPointerException on a commit when I start baasbox. I commented out the transaction logic in DbHelper.java file of baasbox.

The orientdb version is 1.6.3. Has this problem been seen in this version before?

Anybody have an idea about this?

Here is the exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.tx.OTransactionOptimistic$2.run(OTransactionOptimistic.java:145) ~[orientdb-core-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage.commit(OLocalPaginatedStorage.java:1446) ~[orientdb-core-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
Wrapped by: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OStorageException: Error during transaction commit.
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage.commit(OLocalPaginatedStorage.java:1460) ~[orientdb-core-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.tx.OTransactionOptimistic.commit(OTransactionOptimistic.java:176) ~[orientdb-core-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.record.ODatabaseRecordTx.commit(ODatabaseRecordTx.java:115) ~[orientdb-core-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
    at com.baasbox.db.DbHelper.commitTransaction(DbHelper.java:119) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.baasbox.service.user.UserService.signUp(UserService.java:283) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.baasbox.service.user.UserService.createDefaultUsers(UserService.java:74) ~[classes/:na]
```

Answer (score 0):

that statement had been commented because OrientDB 1.6.3 has some limitations (for some of BaasBox use cases) regarding transactions and graph databases.
Those limitations have disappeared with OrientDB 1.7.x.
The result of this is that BaasBox 0.8.4 now fully supports transactions where necessary and the source code of the DbHelper class has indeed been updated.

See https://github.com/baasbox/baasbox/blob/0.8.4/app/com/baasbox/db/DbHelper.java#L130